# If dentro del cshtml para elegir un estilo

Tags: html, c#, css, mvc

Quiero saber cómo puedo hacer para que un **✔** se ubique en un **sí o no** en un formulario dentro **C# MVC** que se define por el valor de un dato en  **SQL**.

Tengo este formulario en **PDF**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que necesito es que el **✔** se ubique en el **SI** o en el **NO** según el valor que tenga en la **BD**. Cuando el valor se encuentra en **1 (uno)** el **✔** debe ir en **SI** pero en caso de que el valor sea **2 (dos)** ó **3(tres)** el **✔** debe ir en **NO**.

El `css` para ubicarlo lo tengo hecho.

Intenté agregar esto en el `cshtml`:

```
if (item.cobDomicilio == "1") {
                    <p class="si">✔</p>
                }else {
                    <p class="no">✔</p>
                    }
                }
```

Pero, en este caso que el valor del cobDomicilio es **1 (uno)** el **✔** me lo marca en el **NO**.
¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas seguro de que el tipo de cobDomicilio es un string?
puedes solucionarlo de dos maneras:

1- Asegurar el tipo de cobDomicilio. y compararlo según su tipo.  Si es intero...

```
if (item.cobDomicilio == 1) {
                <p class="si">✔</p>
            }else {
                <p class="no">✔</p>
                }
            }
```

2- Si no sabes y tipo y asegurar que no si generar un error, seria buena idea convertirlo   a intero.

```
if (Int32.Parse(item.cobDomicilio) == 1) {
                <p class="si">✔</p>
            }else {
                <p class="no">✔</p>
                }
            }
```